# How to understand "abstract-declarator containing an ellipsis shall only be used in a parameter-declaration"

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following quote,It says:
[[dcl.fct]/16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#16)

> A declarator-id or abstract-declarator containing an ellipsis shall only be used in a parameter-declaration.[...]

I agree with **A declarator-id containing an ellipsis shall only be used in a parameter-declaration**,Because we can't use something like `...id-expression` in anywhere,it can only appear in parameter-declaration,so it's 100% clear.However,about **abstract-declarator containing an ellipsis shall only be used in a parameter-declaration**,please consider the below code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
template<typename...T>
void func(T...){
  std::tuple<T...> tup;  //#1
}
```

[[dcl.name]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.name#nt:abstract-declarator)

> type-id:
>
> > type-specifier-seq abstract-declarator(opt)

How about `#1`,it's not parameter-declaration,howerver,the abstract-declarator that contain an ellipsis is used within **type-id** in that context.So,Is my understanding about **abstract-declarator** wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ellipsis is not part of a `type-id`, but of a `template-argument-list`.

If we apply the following grammar from [[temp.names]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names)

```
simple-template-id:
    template-name < template-argument-listopt >

template-name:
    identifier

template-argument-list:
    template-argument ...opt
    [...]

template-argument:
    type-id
    [...]
```

to your example, we get:

```
   std::tuple<T...> tup;
//      tuple<T...>       simple-template-id
//      tuple             template-name
//            T...        template-argument-list
//            T           template-argument, type-id
```

Then, [[temp.arg]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#arg-9)

> A *template-argument* followed by an ellipsis is a pack expansion.

applies, which is what we'd expect.

Comment: you mean that the ellipsis appear here is not as a part of abstract-declarator instead it follows  a template-argument.then Is there a case of abstract-declarator ?

Comment: @jackX That's right. In your example, the ellipsis in `void func(T...)` is an `abstract-declarator` in a `parameter-declaration`.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between `T...` in tuple and `T...` in parameter-list-clause,I think they are all type-id.or In other words,the template-arguments in tuple are also  types,Right?Such as the grammar in your answers,`template-argument: type-id` ,`T` as type-name and `...` as the abstract-declarator.It's my understanding.Is there any quote that can distinct them?

Comment: yes,but,I think `T` in `void func(T...)` is not **template-name**,because `simple-template-id:template-name<template-argument-list(opt)>`,and [[temp.param#3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#3)   ,it says that **A type-parameter whose identifier does not follow an ellipsis defines its identifier to be a typedef-name**,so `T` here is type-name

Comment: yes,but template-name can follow by `<something>`,here `T` is only some type,it is not temlate-name,I think.And [temp.param#3] says that it is a typedef-name,it means it must denote a type,By contrast,a template-name is not a type.

Comment: @jackX In `tuple<T...>`, the `type-id` is `T`, not `T...`; the `...` is part of the `template-argument-list`. In `void func(T...)`, I can't exactly figure out what `T` is. I think it's a `type-name`, but I can't find anything that specifies which kind. [[temp.param]/3] does not apply to template parameter packs, so we can't conclude that it's a `typedef-name`. Let's hope someone more knowledgeable has an answer.

Comment: I think [temp.param]/3 does,it says "A type-parameter whose identifier ",here `T` is the identifier and it also says "does not follow an ellipsis",it means not the case of  "...T",by contrast,here is "T...",so it satisfies this rule.

Comment: @jackX That rule applies to the declaration of the template parameter, i.e. the T in the line `template<typename... T>`, where it follows an ellipsis.

Comment: as you said,`T in the line template<typename... T>` it is the case of following an ellipsis,so the indentifier `T` is not a typedef-name.and the [[temp.param]/3]  says "in the scope of the template declaration",so I think the `T...`  satisfies these rules.It's my reading,I'm not 100% determine.